# maxLength property on TextFormField works only on numbers

Tags: flutter

I noticed that when I have a `TextFormField` with a set `maxLength` property, the text field respects this limit when the input type is: `keyboardType: TextInputType.phone`. But when the input type is `keyboardType: TextInputType.text`, the text field does not respects this limit.

The questions about this issue, does not address this odd behavior.
Many of the answers say that another two properties of the text should be used,
`maxLengthEnforced` and `inputFormatters`, but neither change anything.
The text fields still accepts more characters than the chosen max length (while showing the red error).

```
TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            maxLength: 2,  --> Textfield does not respect this limit
            // maxLengthEnforced: true,  --> No difference
            // inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2)],  --> no difference
            controller: _licenseLetters,
            focusNode: _licenseLettersNode,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
            ),
            onEditingComplete: () => _licenseNumbersNode.requestFocus(),
          ),
```

This text form field below respects the `maxLength` where the input type  is `keyboardType: TextInputType.phone`

```
TextFormField(

      maxLength: 9,
      controller: _landlineController,
      focusNode: _landlineNode,
      validator: validateLandlineNumber,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
      ),
      onEditingComplete: () => _mobileNode.requestFocus(),
    ),
```

The documents states that

`After maxLength characters have been input, additional input is ignored, unless maxLengthEnforced is set to false. The text field enforces the length with a LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter, which is evaluated after the supplied inputFormatters, if any.`

but I did not find this to be true.

Any advise on setting the max length on letters to only two?

Comment: I want to set it to 2 characters

Comment: I see, you need `autocorrect: false` and `enableSuggestions : false,`. If all of them is not working, try `keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,`

Comment: and just use `maxLength: 2` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67236) filed regarding this on GitHub, you can check it out.

It has been fixed in the flutter master channel now, and you should expect it to be available in stable channel the upcoming releases.

Meanwhile, as a workaround you can simulate similar behavior using either of the below methods -

1. **Using the `onChange` callback -**

   You can use the `onChange` callback for the `TextFormField` to enforce length limiting.

   Example -

   ```dart
   onChanged: (value) { 
       String result = value; 
       // Here replace 4 by your maxLength value
       if (result.length > 4) {
           result = result.substring(0, 4); 
       }
       _textFieldController.text = result;
       _textFieldController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
           TextPosition(offset: result.length),
       ); 
   }
   ```
2. **Using your own custom `LengthLimitingInputFormatter` -**

   You can use your own `LengthLimitingInputFormatter` to enforce maximum length.

   Example -

   ```dart
   import 'package:characters/characters.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

   /// TextInputFormatter that fixes the regression.
   /// https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67236
   ///
   /// Remove it once the issue above is fixed.
   class LengthLimitingTextFieldFormatterFixed extends LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter {

      LengthLimitingTextFieldFormatterFixed(int maxLength) : super(maxLength);

      @override
      TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate( TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue, ) {
         if (maxLength != null && maxLength > 0 && newValue.text.characters.length > maxLength) {
         // If already at the maximum and tried to enter even more, keep the old value.
         if (oldValue.text.characters.length == maxLength) {
             return oldValue;
         }
         // ignore: invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member
         return LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter.truncate(newValue, maxLength);
       }

       return newValue;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the input formatter this way..

```
inputFormatters: [
  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(9) //or any number you want
],
```

I know you said you have used the input formatters but you did not specify how and when I went through the same issue before and used it on my textfield it worked.